# Determine tables that takes a part in the query result?

Tags: c++, mariadb, mariasql

I use libmariadb to communicate with mysql server.

- mysql_real_query - to execute queries
- mysql_store_result - to fetch result

Is there a way to figure out from MYSQL_RES (or else), what tables takes a part in the query result?

For example, for query

```
SELECT name, number FROM person INNER JOIN phone ON ...
```

I want discover which fields come from the table 'person' and which from 'phone'.

PS:

1. using aliases in the query is not a solution.
2. postgres API has this functionality through function PQftable, so I
   hope that MariaDB (MySQL) too.

Comment: `SELECT name, number FROM person INNER JOIN phone ON ...` is invalid query for mysql if you have `name` column in both tables you must `SELECT person.name ...` or `SELECT phone.name ...`

Comment: this is just a pseudo query

Comment: is this a pseudo question?

Comment: yes, Alex, you may not answer on it

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: @ Rick James, thanks for suggestion, but I use C++ and MaraDB library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve information about tables for particular fields in the result need to use function:

```
mysql_fetch_field()
```

And get string org_table from MYSQL_FIELD.